# Resized image getting corrupted using Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a azure function app with one input and two outputs. In this case whenever an image is uploaded to a container: originals, the function app will be triggered which will generate two thumbnail images.

[image]

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public static void Run(Stream myBlob,string blobname, string blobextension, Stream outputBlobsm,Stream outputBlobmd, TraceWriter log)
{
    bool smartCropping = true;

    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{blobname} \n Extension: {blobextension} extension");

    var sizesm = imageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Small];    
    log.Info($"C# Blob \n width:{sizesm.Item1} \n height: {sizesm.Item2}");
    ResizeImage(sizesm.Item1, sizesm.Item2,smartCropping,myBlob, outputBlobsm);

    var sizemd = imageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Medium];
    log.Info($"C# Blob \n width:{sizemd.Item1} \n height: {sizemd.Item2}");
    ResizeImage(sizemd.Item1, sizemd.Item2,smartCropping,myBlob, outputBlobmd);
}

public static void ResizeImage(int width, int height, bool smartCropping,Stream myBlob, Stream outputBlob)
{    
    string _apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string _apiUrlBase = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/generateThumbnail";
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiUrlBase);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _apiKey);
        using (HttpContent content = new StreamContent(myBlob))
        {
            //get response
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            var uri = $"{_apiUrlBase}?width={width}&height={height}&smartCropping={smartCropping.ToString()}";
            var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
            var responseBytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

            //write to output thumb
            outputBlob.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
        }
    }
}

public enum ImageSize { ExtraSmall, Small, Medium }

private static Dictionary<ImageSize, (int, int)> imageDimensionsTable = new Dictionary<ImageSize, (int, int)>() {
    { ImageSize.ExtraSmall, (320, 200) },
    { ImageSize.Small,      (640, 400) },
    { ImageSize.Medium,     (800, 600) }
};
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Which issue exactly?

Comment: What happens if you try to write just one of the files? I have a suspicion that you're just appending the two thumbnails together into one blob.

Comment: The first image: {blobname}-sm.{blobextension} gets created but the second one : {blobname}-md.{blobextension} gets corrupted.  // thumbs/{blobname}-md.{blobextension}
    var sizemd = imageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Medium];
    log.Info($"C# Blob \n width:{sizemd.Item1} \n height: {sizemd.Item2}");
    ResizeImage(sizemd.Item1, sizemd.Item2,smartCropping,myBlob, outputBlobmd);

Comment: I tested with different image combinations and see sometimes the first image:{blobname}-sm.{blobextension} getting corrupted

Comment: Do you see any issues with the code in that case please help me to rectify it here in this case.

Comment: It seems like mime type is getting corrupted here in this case. Any corrections here are much helpful to me.

Comment: On further analysis I see the second image  : {blobname}-md.{blobextension} is getting generated with type: text/plain which is not correct in this case.