# Azure HTTPTrigger Post Request Upload File

Tags: java, azure, http-post

I am trying to upload a file via a POST request. Using the `HttpRequestMessage<File>` gives me the error below. If I use `HttpRequestMessage<byte[]>` the code works but I am missing the meta-data like file name and other details which I need to upload as well.

Code:

```
@FunctionName("HttpExample")
    public String run(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<File> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) { ... }
```

Error:

```
Executed 'Functions.HttpExample' (Failed, Id=7349f061-9213-4607-a757-8231c41078d2)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpExample. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[27/02/2020 10:18:15] Exception: ClassCastException: Cannot convert com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource@74386ca9to type com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage<java.io.File>
[27/02/2020 10:18:15] Stack: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot convert com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource@74386ca9to type com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage<java.io.File>
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.DataOperations.generalAssignment(DataOperations.java:191)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.DataOperations.apply(DataOperations.java:120)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.DataSource.computeByType(DataSource.java:56)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource.computeByType(RpcHttpRequestDataSource.java:20)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.DataSource.computeByName(DataSource.java:42)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.RpcHttpRequestDataSource.computeByName(RpcHttpRequestDataSource.java:20)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.BindingDataStore.getDataByName(BindingDataStore.java:55)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:59)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:42)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:52)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:53)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[27/02/2020 10:18:15] .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to directly use File. There is not implementation for converting your request to `HttpRequestMessage<java.util.Optional<java.io.File>>`.

**A solution** is to upload file with `multipart/form-data`. There is already a post about this, you may refer to: [upload with multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54511067/10223674). There is also a known problem: Azure function will lose some unreadable bytes, to solve it, you may see the update in that answer.

**Another easier solution**, is to keep using byte array. However, at the same time, you may put the file name and other metadatas into query parameters. For example: `?filename=xxx&other=xxxx`.

Then you can get file content from byte array, and all the metadatas from query parameters:

```
    @FunctionName("HttpExample")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<byte[]>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        byte[] body = request.getBody().get();

        Map<String, String> queryParameters = request.getQueryParameters();
        String fileName = queryParameters.get("fileName");

        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(fileName + " -> " + new String(body)).build();
    }
```

[image]