# How to get multipart form data with Azure Functions Java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, serverless

Hi how do I get `multipart form data` in case of **Java** `Azure Function Apps` ?

I have looked at the [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-java#example) but there is no mention of multipart form data

```
public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.POST},
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // This gives me the whole body
        final String file = request.getBody().get();

        System.out.println(file);

}
```

How can I filter out just my upload ?

I seem to be having no API for this. I can access the whole body and that's it.

**How do I do this in Java ?**

Comment: There seems to be no simple solution for this. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473126/azure-functions-how-to-use-the-multiparthttpservletrequest-class-from-the-de

Comment: @Lesrac Wow, that's tough to do.